# Android Studio Error Code: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 5s 602ms

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

### When I run my app I get this: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

This is gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\JUNZHISHAN Zhu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout102Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2530Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2530Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 487819257): libpng error: Not a PNG file

Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.495 secs
```

And this is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '25.3.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I had a error about Android Studio to run a file. I just add a new XML file in Layout and new JAVA file trying to create a new activity by swiping gesture. then error happened. Yesterday the file worked well. I'm new to code and and android studio. Can anyone help me to solve this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there is no platforms directory in your sdk folder.

Comment: Have you actually checked what the error suggests in the 6 top lines?

Comment: It seems one of your drawable resources has a problem and causes ":app:mergeDebugResources" task to fail. See this line: "AAPT err(Facade for 487819257): libpng error: Not a PNG file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AAPT err(Facade for 487819257): libpng error: Not a PNG file
>
> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Your **`PNG`** image is not well formed .

You should add this in your <kbd>build.gradle</kbd> section .

```
android 
{ 
   aaptOptions
   {
   cruncherEnabled = false
   } 
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** .

Comment: THANNNKK UUU! It works! But I actually never use libpng and it even didn't show in my drawable folder. I don't know why this error happen.

Comment: @yueyang Glad to hear .